# Laravel - Error: App\Exports\View must be compatible with Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView::view(): Illuminate\Contracts\View\View

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to export to excel using PHP 7, Laravel 5.8, Maatwebsite Excel 3.1.  I successfully display on the view blade and also perform the filter.

Model:
use App\UserResponse;

**Controller**

```php
public function userresponseReport(Request $request,$export=false)
{
    $data['title'] = 'User Response';

    $userresponses = DB::table('user_response as g')
        ->select(
        //DB::raw('DATE(g.created_at) as created_date'),
            DB::raw('g.created_at as created_date'),
            'g.msisdn',
            'g.game_code',
            'g.answer',
            'g.answer_code',
            'g.Amount_charged',
            'g.payment_ref',
            'g.status',
            'g.user_channel'
        )
        ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC');

    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $end_date = $request->end_date;

    $render=[];
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }
    if(isset($request->msisdn))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('msisdn','like','%'.$request->msisdn.'%');
        $render['msisdn']=$request->msisdn;
    }
    if(isset($request->game_code))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('game_code','like','%'.$request->game_code.'%');
        $render['game_code']=$request->game_code;
    }
    if(isset($request->user_channel))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('user_channel','like','%'.$request->user_channel.'%');
        $render['user_channel']=$request->user_channel;
    }

    if(!empty($export))
    {
        return Excel::download(new UserresponseExport($userresponses->get()), 'userresponse.xlsx');
    }
    $userresponses= $userresponses->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $userresponses= $userresponses->paginate(15);
    $userresponses= $userresponses->appends($render);
    $data['userresponses'] = $userresponses;

    return view('report.userresponseReport',$data);
}
```

Then after that, the view blade:

**userresponseReport.blade.php**

```html
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('msisdn',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'MSISDN']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('game_code',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Game Code']) }}
        </div>   
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('user_channel',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Channel']) }}
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ Form::date('start_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ Form::date('end_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>          
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
            <a href="{{ route('userresponseReport',['export']) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>


<div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condesed" id="commenter_info_table">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>MSISDN</td>
            <td>Game Code</td>
            <td>Game Name</td>
            <td>Answer</td>
            <td>Channel</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($userresponses as $key => $userresponse)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
<!--                <td>{{ $userresponse->created_date }}</td>-->
                <td>{{ date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime($userresponse->created_date)) }}</td>
                <td>{{ $userresponse->msisdn }}</td>
                <td>{{ $userresponse->game_code }}</td>
                <td> 
                    @if($userresponse->game_code=='101')
                       Trivia
                    @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='102')
                       Predict and Win 
                    @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='103')
                       Party With the BBN 
                    @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='104')
                       Grand Prize  
                    @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='105')
                       Happy Hour    
                    @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='106')
                       Power Boost                         
                    @endif                       
                </td>                
                <td>{{ $userresponse->answer }}</td>
                <td>{{ $userresponse->user_channel }}</td>                                    
            </tr>          
        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="14">
                {{ $userresponses->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>         
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Then the Export

**UserresponseExport**

```php
class UserresponseExport implements FromView, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents, WithMapping
{
    protected $userresponses;

    public function __construct($userresponses = null)
    {
        $this->userresponses = $userresponses;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('report.userresponseReport', [
            'userresponses' => $this->userresponses ?: DB::table('user_response as g')
                ->select(
                    DB::raw('g.created_at as created_date'),
                    'g.msisdn',
                    'g.game_code',
                    'g.answer',
                    'g.answer_code',
                    'g.Amount_charged',
                    'g.payment_ref',
                    'g.status',
                    'g.user_channel'
                )
                ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC')
        ]);
    }

    private $headings = [
        'Date Created',
        'MSISDN',
        'game_code',
        'Answer',
        'Channel'
    ];
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings;
    }


    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $cellRange = 'A1:E1'; // All headers
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);

            },


        ];
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/report/userresponse-report/{export?}', ['as' => 'userresponseReport', 'uses' => 'ReportController@userresponseReport']);
```

On the view blade, when I clicked on search everything was okay. But when I click on export, I got this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Declaration of App\Exports\UserresponseExport::view(): App\Exports\View must be compatible with Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView::view(): Illuminate\Contracts\View\View

[image: export_error]

1. What could have caused this error?
2. How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error indicates that your class `App\Exports\UserresponseExport` is not following the interface correctly.

By the error we can see that you need to have a method named `view` which you have, but your method have typehinted `App\Exports\View` as the return type instead of `Illuminate\Contracts\View\View`.

To fix this simply change your `view` method return type to `Illuminate\Contracts\View\View`.

Your code right now most likely says

```
public function view(): View 
{
  ...
}
```

But as you are missing `use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;` in your import statements, `View` is getting resolved to the current namespace of your class + the class you are trying to typehint, which results in `App\Exports\View`.

So another solution to this instead of typehinting the full namespace is to import `Illuminate\Contracts\View\View`, in your class by adding `use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;` at the top of your file.